# How to filter commits with git grep that only starts with a "word"?

Tags: git

I am trying to use 'git log --grep' to only return commits that starts with "word". I have tried 'git log --grep="word"'. However, this returns all commits that contain the string "word" anywhere in the commit message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The --grep option supports regex. So try the following command:
`git log --grep="^word"`

Comment: This will only search the current branch. Add `--all` to search all branches.

Answer (score 1):

- To grep all commits that start with `word`, use:

  ```
   git log --grep="^word"
  ```

  Here `^` matches the start of the line.
- To grep all commits that end with `word`, use:

  ```
  git log --grep='word$'
  ```

  Here `$` matches the end of a line.
- To grep all commits that contains `word` as substring, use:

  ```
  git log --grep='word'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For all **Windows** command line users:

The approved answer wasn't working and even with '^' the word was searched somewhere in the commit message.

This worked for me:

```
git log --grep="^word" --extended-regexp
```